# Passing LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS to catkin_make

Tags: ros, catkin, rosbridge, macosx, homebrew

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) on Mac OS X, which depends on [rosauth](http://wiki.ros.org/rosauth), which in turn depends on `libssl-dev`

I've installed `openssl` on OS X via Homebrew, but it's keg-only since Apple uses its own libraries.
Therefore, compilation of `rosauth` fails with:

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object rosauth/CMakeFiles/ros_mac_authentication_test.dir/test/ros_mac_authentication_test.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object rosauth/CMakeFiles/ros_mac_authentication.dir/src/ros_mac_authentication.cpp.o
/Users/smaniato/Cornell/Research/Projects/behaviors_ws/src/rosauth/src/ros_mac_authentication.cpp:15:10: fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found
#include <openssl/sha.h>
```

Homebrew says that I have to manually add the following build variables:

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

How do I pass those to `catkin_make`? I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
catkin_make -D LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

I'm also OK with modifying `CMakeLists.txt`, since I'm building from source. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233366/passing-ldflags-and-cppflags-to-catkin_make/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how to pass this via command line.

If you want to adapt the `CMakeLists.txt`, you should be able to add the respective directories easily:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/opt/openssl/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib)
```

make sure to add them before you create the respective targets.

However, imho it would be better to let this be handled by `find_package`, but I don't know if and how this works in OS X...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-02**:
Thanks! I'll try adding those directories to `CMakeLists.txt` later today. I'll get back to you :-)

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-03**:
Yep, it worked. I'll mark your answer as correct :-)